# How many people does わたしが世界で一番愛してる人 refer to?

Tags: translation

In the sentence わたしが世界で一番愛してる人に。is there a nuance that indicates how many people it refers to? (one or several people).

Comment: I would say *one* because of the superlative. But the sentence itself is ambiguous it can be either *To the people I love the most* or *To the person I love the most*.

Comment: @道理百遍義理一遍 This is the whole sentence (for context).
わたしが世界で一番愛してる人に。
…わたしを世界で二番目に愛してくれてる人に It is being said to just one person.

Comment: Definitively, one. Because of the 一番 vs. 二番 part.

Comment: @道理百遍義理一遍 So it would be something like: to the one that I love more than anyone in the world; to the one that loves me second in the world? Are you sure?

Comment: 99% sure that's why I let the answer to somebody with more insight. But I would be very surprised if it is not the case.

Comment: Without any context the answer is 1 person. If it's being verbally said to just one person then it is just one person with 100% certainty (even if it's a lie) as otherwise it would be gramaticaly incorrect. Japanese usually omits pronouns but all you have to do is take a look at the previous sentence or know to whom it is being said. If it is being verbally said to just one person then there's no room for misunderstandings as otherwise it would be gramatically incorrect and it would need the plural japanese form (certainly not your sentence) to signal some very weird contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[道理百遍義理一遍](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4216)'s comments above are quite right, and the answer below is likely to be merely a restatement of them.

When I look at the phrase

> わたしが世界で一番愛してる人

it is actually ambiguous whether the "人" here is singular or plural, but  without context, it's much more likely to be "the person" because of the superlative (and probably the nature of love). It can also be understood as "the people I love the most" naturally with proper context. For example, I have found a blog post where the writer's parents are described this way.

With the context given in the comment,

> わたしが世界で一番愛してる人に。 …わたしを世界で二番目に愛してくれてる人に

there is no ambiguity I can come up with; it's singular.

- It is clear from the structure that the two "人" here refer to the same object.
- Thus the entire structure becomes "To [the one / the people] 1. whom I love the most and 2. whom love[s] me the second most dearly". There's sadly someone else who the "人" loves the most. This is apparently about personal relations and therefore is singular.

---

(I had some free time to spend and below is what it brought me; not a serious answer)

Given some extreme situations, the sentence above could be interpreted as plural. Let's pretend you are an ancient spirit, worshiped and beloved by the local people. You love them back and give them your favour. At one time however, the people start to believe in something different (imagine Christianity or science or whatever) and now you are now second-most beloved thing for them. They still worship you but it's more like a tradition than a living faith. Now you can use that expression to refer to the local people.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, the sentence comes from a VN. I just asked a japanese youtuber (that read that VN) the same question. The answer was "You should have given the stackexchange people the whole line to read. The first part of it (だって、鍛えられましたから) makes the line easier to understand. Japanese is a contextual language and things are often omitted. If you need help with any sort of translation, always include as much context as possible, and give them the entire line, or preferably multiple lines, to work with. They're correct, by the way. It is singular. "

Comment: "She's saying she was trained by the person she loves the most (singular, the boy), and by the person(boy) who loves her the second most (second to the other girl). Both of these refer to the same person, the boy, she just describes him in 2 ways." I will give you the context as he says. The girl had just asked the boy to tell her she's the girl she loves the most. The boy says that and the girl says he's a liar. Now that you know the context, does your answer change? Is the first part of the sentence  (だって、鍛えられましたから) relevant?

Comment: @Mer Sorry to be late. In this case I don't think the first part changed my interpretation, nor does it make it easier for me to interpret. "わたしを世界で二番目に愛してくれてる人に" part is quite relevant, but that is enough for me.

Comment: Yes, it is as you said in your answer "This is apparently about personal relations and therefore is singular". The same that  道理百遍義理一遍 had said ("Definitively, one. Because of the 一番 vs. 二番 part") I also asked one more japanese youtuber that read the source material and he said that "this line is trying to highlight the juxtaposition between her loving him the most but him loving her the second most. There's no ambiguity".

Comment: I later asked another person that knows japanese and also read the source material and the answer was: It's about whom he loves. She believes she is second in his heart. He had told her she was the girl he loved most and she had called him a liar. The full sentence would be that she's been trained very hard by the person she loves most in the world but only loves her second most (he had betrayed her several times even though they are a fully fledged couple and he's not supposed to sleep with other women).